# Overriding a singleton with a scoped proxy

Tags: java, spring, testing, inheritance, scope

In Spring, is it possible to override a singleton bean definition with a scoped proxy?
Namely, if I have some

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public Foo foo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

I want to create a test configuration but with a custom scope for "Foo":

```
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfiguration extends MyConfiguration
{
    @Override
    @Scope(value="myTestScope", proxyMode=ScopedProxy.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Foo foo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work! The constructed `Foo` is *still* a singleton! Unfortunately, adding @Primary and adding @Bean annotations to the test configuration doesn't help either. Is there any way to override a singleton with a scoped proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The valid scopes values are :

> 1. singleton – Return a single bean instance per Spring IoC container
> 2. prototype – Return a new bean instance each time when requested
> 3. request – Return a single bean instance per HTTP request.  session –
> 4. Return a single bean instance per HTTP session.  globalSession –
> 5. Return a single bean instance per global HTTP session.

Comment: Not quite. Since Spring 2.0: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom

You can create your own custom scope, and that's clearly what I have here...